# How to use certain parts of a JSON and put it in an alert (Plain Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I would like a bookmarklet that when I click on it, it goes to the JSON and grabs the "temp" from there, and puts it into an alert to tell me what the weather It with a click of a button.
Is there a way to do it? Or do I have to use a different API?

This is what I've so far:

```
function insertReply(content) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = content;
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=australia,wa&mode=json';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. First, realize that that API seems to support JSONP. That is, if you provide it with a `callback` parameter, it will wrap the response with `<callback>(...)` where `<callback>` is the value of the `callback` parameter. That means that you could use this URL:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=australia,wa&mode=json&callback=insertReply
```

and your `insertReply` function would be provided with an appropriate object. Then, if you want to grab `temp` out of it, just use `content` as an object:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = content.list[0].main.temp;
```

Comment: I did this, and it didn't work, so I tested it on jsconsole.com and it says content is undefined...

Comment: @user3521680: I just tried it on http://www.jsconsole.com/ and it works fine for me. I also tried it on JSFiddle, where [it also works](http://jsfiddle.net/A3xKS/).

Comment: @user3521680: Yes; it's in the JSFiddle link.